# Trying to use a domain name on a Ubuntu server - Server Error (500) / Internal server error

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, apache-2.4

I want to access my website with my domain name. The site is accessible on its IP address. I have directed godaddy dns servers to this IP. Everything should be fine there and in fact, I can access a page www.mysite.com/home/wordpress to display the site. Much rather I would see this page as the landing page for www.mysite.com, without the complete address.

The server is Ubuntu 16.04, Apache2.

My apache configuration file in sites-enabled/default.conf

is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/home/wordpress"
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    ServerAlias mysite.com
```

and my django settings file settings.py has a line:
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

accessing mysite.com, I get

```
Server Error (500)
```

and apache error log:

```
 DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'mysite.com'. You may need to add u'mysite.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS
```

when I edit settings.py and add
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [mydomain.com]

this time I will get

```
Internal Server Error
```

error log:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [mydomain.com]
NameError: name ‘mydomain’ is not defined
```

Comment: How is your django settings file related to that? If you want that Wordpress (PHP) handles the domain, you need to take Python out of the way.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! in the same <virtualhost*:80> I have: WSGIScriptAlias / /home/mysite/apache/wsgi.py - commenting this out and killing the python program could then maybe solve the issue, but what would be a way to host both the django &  wordpress ?

Comment: You shouldn't need this line. As I said, Wordpress uses PHP and don't need WSGI.

Comment: You should be able to move the WSGI handler into a `<location>` block, eg. `/django` so it only acts for URLS like `example.com/django/`.

Comment: is this not a straight forward Python syntax error - i.e. should it not be ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mydomain.com'] (do you need the square brackets too?)

Comment: As simple it was - thank you! Reconfiguring the apache configuration file for both services is the solution. AND also the single quotation marks should be in the ALLOWED_HOSTS. oops!